# How to set up Google captcha in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, recaptcha

You need to do a captcha validation so that the data is not saved in the database if the captcha is not correct.
Here is the controller where the form is saved and validated.

> Ronis\Feedback\Controller\Index\Post.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Ronis\Feedback\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Ronis\Feedback\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Post extends \Ronis\Feedback\Controller\Index implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    protected $httpHeader;
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @var MailInterface
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader,
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ConfigInterface $feedbackConfig
     * @param MailInterface $mail
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader,
        ConfigInterface $feedbackConfig,
        MailInterface $mail,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        LoggerInterface $logger = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $feedbackConfig);
        $this->httpHeader = $httpHeader;
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        try {
            $this->addDataBd($this->validatedParams());
            $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('feedback');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->dataPersistor->set('feedback', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->set('feedback', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('feedback/index');
    }

    //6LcRJZcUAAAAAA0_SbrE_fHW1zbaJ3JnpMlwUwkt - site

    //6LcRJZcUAAAAALfF-aLq9804zowngpLlcu_Qi1-P - secret
    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function validatedParams()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (trim($request->getParam('feedback_name')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the Name and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('feedback_content')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the comment and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('feedback_subject')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the subject and try again.'));
        }
        if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('feedback_email'), '@')) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.'));
        }

        return $request->getParams();
    }
    private function addDataBd(){
        $objctManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $feedback = $objctManager->create('Ronis\Feedback\Model\Feedback');

        $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('feedback_name');
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('feedback_email');
        $phone = $this->getRequest()->getPost('feedback_telephone');
        $userAgent = $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();
        $remote = $objctManager->get('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress'); //remote ip
        $subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('feedback_subject');
        $other_subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('other_subject');
        $message = $this->getRequest()->getPost('feedback_content');

        $feedback->setData('feedback_name', $name);
        $feedback->setData('feedback_email', $email);
        $feedback->setData('feedback_telephone', $phone);
        if($subject == 'other'){
            $feedback->setData('feedback_subject', $other_subject);
        }
        else {
        $feedback->setData('feedback_subject', $subject);
        }
        $feedback->setData('feedback_content', $message);
        $feedback->setData('is_active', 0);
        $feedback->setData('feedback_user_agent', $userAgent);
        $feedback->setData('feedback_remote_ip', $remote->getRemoteAddress());
        $feedback->save();
    }

    /**
     * @param array $post Post data from feedback form
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendEmail($post)
    {
        $this->mail->send(
            $post['feedback_email'],
            ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 already has extension for google captcha. You can check the below post from magento.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/extension-install-google-recaptcha.html

You can extend that module in your layout file to add the captcha in your form which will solve your problem.

Comment: Magento provide google default captcha in Higher than Magento version 2.3.x

Comment: Not older version of  2.3.x

Comment: So there you can choose only basic forms, and how can I do for my custom form that I use in the module

Comment: you can extend the module functionality to your module and show the necessary template in your layout file. And you have check @ChiragPatel answer also. It supports only m2.3.x version.